# Cannot add scope in Uber Developer Dashboard

Tags: uber-api

I'm trying to authenticate against the Uber REST API using Auth 2.0, but there seems to be a problem with scopes. As soon as I specify a scope (even non privileged ones), the /authorize request fails with "Invalid scope". If I exclude the scope parameter it seems to work fine.

The developer dashboard tells me to enter the scopes I want to use, but there is no way to do this on the Auth page.

[image: missing input?]

It looks like I should have a way to select scopes here but there is no input at all. (Tried different browsers, ad-block turned off, etc).

I also cannot find the "Request Full Access" button, which should be visible according to the Scopes guide in the Uber developer portal.

I have entered all information under Settings, except "Origin URIs" which is not relevant for my implementation.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Any answer to this question yet?

Comment: Facing the same problem in uber API for deliveries....

Answer (score 0):

The request full access button is inside the Trip Branding page

Answer (score -1):

Your application currently does not have access to any scopes. Please contact your Uber business development representative or Uber point of contact to request access.

Maybe the above words can help you.

Comment: That kind of answer is not an answer. This is clue you can write that in question comments. Please edit/delete answer.

Comment: I don't know are it is unclear answer. In my opinion, it's not an answer, it's a clue with should be in question comment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31406510)